# How many files should the borg-backup cache contain and how can I clean it?

Tags: cache, borg-backup

I use borg-backup for making backups. Because of filling my root partition, I encountered its cache files, that take up several GB:

```
# ls -al /root/.cache/borg/
total 4
drwx------ 1 root root 792 23 apr  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  70 30 jan 16:27 ..
drwx------ 1 root root  92 29 jan 22:36 2f4090b173de95b68e1b9a7bf259ac55667e9e8d548924b72ac70a28c696bf96
drwx------ 1 root root  98  8 apr  2019 b0c0ba21824b20bbfac6fcabf3fd10a1e6176b11766cfe477b85c8233d165d85
drwx------ 1 root root  78  1 feb 13:54 c4ac2a63c0cefd6f67c1bdfa7c512575c08b2f41cf8c03bcc6dd10686d0ad2f4
-rw------- 1 root root 194 27 okt  2016 CACHEDIR.TAG
drwx------ 1 root root  78 24 jan 09:36 cf95bd49b26cc8182b1d94b4bcbecf19d17d3596faedc4d76638c87bf6f676a2
drwx------ 1 root root  78  1 apr  2019 d10873b16123c63e5f9bdb92f02cfaef9bcd9d6befc0b1500e880cfa50210cf5
drwx------ 1 root root  78 13 mrt  2019 ef7a663a561b3f15cf400c973e58e797b4bfd47f83a4a8580019322115e9df03
```

How many of these should I keep and how can I get rid of the other ones in an automated way?

Answer (score 3):

I received an answer via chat: There should be as many directories as there are repositories I'm making a backup to. The others (directories for now-defunct repositories in my case) can be simply removed. The ‘config’ file in the directories contains the information necessary to see for which repository the directory is.